# Matching values in two record ins mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to match the comma separated values in one column of two records in mysql

I have two records like

please check this screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1g51fy7hcwun33/ques.jpg

What I really want is the number of matching values on values_array column in both records.
or just the values matching in both records.

like

**match_value_count**

5

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You do this with a lot of pain.  Introduce a junction table so querying the data will be easier (that is a table with one row per user and value).

Comment: I already getting this data after joining two table one is user and one is user_field_values..

Comment: You should edit the question and show the original data and your desired results.

Comment: I have edited and added a screenshot so now can you understand what i want to do with these two records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution so I'm sharing with everyone who is also searching for it..

```
SELECT `engine4_users`.*, COUNT(value) AS `count` FROM `engine4_users`
INNER JOIN `engine4_user_fields_values` ON engine4_user_fields_values.item_id = engine4_users.user_id WHERE (engine4_users.user_id NOT IN (4)) AND (engine4_users.user_id != 1) AND (engine4_user_fields_values.value IN ('1', 'Mubasher ', 'Munir', '2', '1993-6-29', 'Lahore', '54000', '5', '10', 'Video Gaming', 'Transporter ', 'OOP', 'Akcent', 'Star Movies', '1', '21', '2010-1-2', 'nothing', '', '2012-1-4', 'Nothing', 'Others', '22', 'Nothing')) GROUP BY `item_id` HAVING (count(value) > 1) ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

see img for reference
https://www.dropbox.com/s/28w9uckvar9uvf1/answ.jpg